# Disable past dates of jQuery DatePicker in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have troubles to create datepicker in my project. I need to disable past dates. I tried everything I think but nothing works. I also need to keep the value of input. Can anybody please help me with that?

I tried minDate in script but it's not working.

```
@model EscapeGame2.ViewModels.RoomInfoViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datefield').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });  
</script>

<h1>Details</h1>

 <div>
    <h4>Room</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="datefield" data-val="true" data-val-required="Date is required"
               id="ReleaseDate" name="ReleaseDate" type="date" value="1/11/1989" />
    </dt>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable past dates in `jQuery` `DatePicker` you have to use `new Date()` for `minDate` value as follows:

```
 $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        minDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @model EscapeGame2.ViewModels.RoomInfoViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });  
</script>

<h1>Details</h1>

 <div>
    <h4>Room</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-required="Date is required"  id="ReleaseDate" name="ReleaseDate" type="date" value="1/11/1989" />
    </dt>
</dl>
```

Comment: The same result as I had before. Last dates are still available.

Comment: you need to chage into two place one class="datepicker" and  $('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });